# Java Interface Implement

Tags: java, interface, implements

I am studying Java, Spring and POI. I see https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html and follow it.
At "New WorkBook", next code exists.

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xlsx");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Running above code, it works well.
I found out that "Workbook" is NOT class BUT interface. I learned that interface HAVE TO be implemented. But I CANNOT found the implementation. Where is it implemented? What must I study to comprehend it?

Comment: `XSSFWorkbook` implements `Workbook`

Comment: If you are using an IDE, such as Eclipse or IntelliJ, you can place your cursor on `XSSFWorkbook` and hit F3 or right  click on it to jump to the definition of the class. If you are using just a simple editor and the command line, you can run a search in your file system for `XSSFWorkbook.java` and/or `XSSFWorkbook.class` to find the implementation.

Comment: @Raul Santelices Thank you your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oficial Oracle tutorial about interfaces:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Answer (score 0):

That is interface instance. 
Details: [Using an Interface as a Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html)

In short, you can create instance of interface.

**Case 1:** for [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

```
Workbook wb = new Workbook() {
// Some implementation
}
```

**Case 2:** Use it as type. (Yes! your case!)

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

see also: [Strategy Design Pattern in Java.](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/strategy-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial.html) It is very useful idea.